# How can I add a new row between two existing rows in a excel file using perl?

Tags: perl, spreadsheet, xls

I want to modify an existing excel file using Perl. So, right now I am using the Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser for that. Using the Addcell command I am able to modify any cell.

But now I want to add new rows between two existing rows which I am unable to do. I have provided a code below.

So, using this I can use the commands of the module Spreadsheet::WriteExcel too. Please suggest a command from the module Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser or Spreadsheet::WriteExcel which can help me add a new row between two existing rows.

This question is cross-posted on perlmonks :
https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=11101921

```
my $workbook = $template->SaveAs('newfile.xls');

my $worksheet1  = $workbook->sheets(0);
my $north = $workbook->add_worksheet('North');

$worksheet1->write($row+2, $col, "World2");

$workbook->close();
```

Comment: link for the writeExcel module
https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Comment: Do you want to add a row at the end or in the middle?

Comment: I want to add the row in the middle